# Javascript add in for loop to disregard various nodes in list if text content is found

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

I have a query into my HTML document using querySelector and querySelectorAll which gets all li ignoring those that has a, here is the code:

```
var number2 = number;

var otherSubjRow = document.querySelector("#exploreTable");
if(otherSubjRow) {
var otherSubjCells = Row.querySelectorAll("li");
if (typeof(otherSubjCells) != 'undefined' && Cells != null)
{
l = otherSubjCells.length;
var otherSubjects = ""
var number2 = number;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

    if (otherSubjCells[i].querySelectorAll("a").length < 1) {
     otherSubjCells[i].innerText + " ");
     otherSubjects += number2 + "." + otherSubjCells[i].innerText + " "; 
     number2++      
  }
}
}
```

Here is a snippet of my document:

```
 <table id="exploreTable">
    ...
 <tr>
 <li>
  <a></a>
 </li>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <ul><li>International relations -- Handbook
  <a></a>
 </li></ul>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <ul><li>Titles by: Jose, Charles, editor.
  <a></a>
 </li></ul>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <ul><li>Series: Policy brief ; no. 2016-03
  <a></a>
 </li></ul>
 </td></tr>
 </table>
```

The thing is I want to ignore capturing in my for loop all text that contains in the beginning of the text "Series: " and "Titles by: ". I'm trying it to add it here by using ||:

```
 if (otherSubjCells[i].querySelectorAll("a").length < 1)
```

But not quite sure if it is the correct way to do it. Or add another if in the statement? Any ideas on how to go about it? Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Can you share for us array of element which you want see?

Comment: From the li text, I only want to capture "International relations -- Handbook" which does not have in the beginning of the text the following: "Series: " and "Titles by: "

Comment: so if i correct understand you, you need all `li` in `exploreTable` which does not have in the beginning of the text the following: "Series: " and "Titles by: "

Comment: Yes, that's what I need! Thanks!

Comment: I prepare for you my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440772/10761855, it's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <table id="exploreTable">
        <tr>
            <li>
                <a></a>
            </li>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>International relations -- Handbook
                        <a></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Titles by: Jose, Charles, editor.
                        <a></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Series: Policy brief ; no. 2016-03
                        <a></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      const arr = document.getElementById("exploreTable").querySelectorAll('li');
      const result = [].filter.call(arr,(el)=>{
        return !(el.textContent.indexOf("Series:") === 0||el.textContent.indexOf("Titles by:") === 0)
      });
      const resText = result.map((el, index)=>{
         return `${index+1} ${el.textContent}`;
      });
      console.log(result);
      console.log(resText);

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi! I am getting object HTMLLIElement when I ran the code.

Comment: Hi Vadim Hulevich! The code works as is, I'm trying to figure out how to add it into my code. Thanks, cheers and have a nice day!